# How to add a JUnit 4 test to a JUnit 3 test suite

Tags: junit, junit4, test-suite, junit3

I want to add a JUnit 4 test to a legacy project which uses JUnit 3 test suites ("AllTests") to organize the tests.

The tests are already executed with JUnit 4, so I know that JUnit 4 tests work in principle. I just forgot how to add the JUnit 4 test class to the `junit.framework.TestSuite` instance. Anyone with the code snippet?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's as easy as this:

```java
public static Test suite() {
    TestSuite suite = new TestSuite("suite name");
    suite.addTestSuite(JUnit3Test.class);

    suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(JUnit4Test.class));  // <--

    return suite;
}
```